# resizable iframe with handle within frame?

Tags: javascript, iframe

just wondering if anyone knows if this is possible? and also, if its feasible, id prefer pure javascript on the parent document (i.e no jquery/libraries).

take a look at jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/default.html. thats the resizable that i mean, and the handle is the little shape in the bottom right of the element.

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "resizable" - scroll bars or something else? What do you mean by "with handle" - what handle? You'll have to explain before anyone can help you..

Comment: I'm not sure you got notification for my comment below, change your display name so that people can address you using `@`.

Answer (score 0):

The `resizable` plugin is not working well with `iframe` as far as I could see.

One work around would be to use `div` instead of frame and load the other page contents into that div e.g.

```
$("#MyFrameDiv").load("MyPage.php");
```

Then you can make that div resizable without any problem.

Comment: great, but is it possible to achieve this without jquery? thanks.

Comment: Of course, but it means writing your own hundreds if not thousands of lines of JavaScript code. It's like building a house using bricks: you can either enter house already made by someone else who spent time and effort, or you can build it yourself brick after brick, and the final result will be pretty much the same.